# Can not edit data in a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, heidisql

I've got a database with several tables in MySQL. All of the tables are editable using workbench and HeidiSQL, except one. I used HeidiSQL to import a CSV file into a new table called spissues. When I select * from that table, the option to edit does not appear. Although all other tables the edit option is available. I've tried this directly on the server machine as root, remotely as a user that has most of the same permissions as root, and remotely as the regular user. They all have full permissions (the regular doesn't have Admin roles, but does have full Schema rights). Can anyone suggest something to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very possible you have not defined a primary key on the table that doesn't have an edit user interface. HeidiSQL and Workbench both need a primary key to be able to replace rows in the table from their table-edit user interfaces.

Comment: That was it! I was trying to modify the table so that I could fix the column that was going to be used as the primary key. So instead I just set the pk first, now I'll modify it and reset the type. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only talked about Workbench, not HeidiSQL. Because HeidiSQL lets you edit data without a primary key, by taking all columns into the `UPDATE..WHERE` query.